# API call Throwing error during verification in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, api

I am try to make an API call with below code . I am able to print till "getMMHost();" in below code . **After that , I get error as :**

```html
[java] org.apache.http.impl.client.ClientParamsStack@3e694b3f
[java] res  code  : 405
[java] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**Code :**

```js
String url ="/api//sr?bid="+cluster+"&mode=1";
 System.out.println(url);  
 
 HttpHost httpHost = getMMHost();
 System.out.println(httpHost);  //(I am able to print till here )
 

 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = (DefaultHttpClient) verifiedClient(new DefaultHttpClient());
 
 
 HttpPost httpost = verifiedPost(url,user,password);
 
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpHost, httpost);
 
 System.out.println(response.getParams());
 int respCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I aint sure if the info I have provided is enough . Can it be related to the SSL of httpClient ? DO I need to POST the URL and the credentials ? THis thing is driving me crazy .Any help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The error as visible from the response code is 405 , which basically means that the method is not allowed . So , if u get 405 error , its basically because u are using post() in place of get() or vice versa . Or, any one of get() post() put() update() in a wrong place .